# Why is this statement not undefined?

Tags: javascript

I created an object Person and assigned a display function to it. But if I call that function out of the object it says that `this.name` is not undefined. So what is it? I mean, why empty string instead of undefined..

```
<script>

function Person(n)
{
    this.name = n;
    this.display = display;
}

function display()
{
    console.log('Hi, ' + this.name + '!');
    console.log(this.name === undefined);
}

var person = new Person("John");
person.display();

display(); // here!!

</script>
```

Output:

```
Hi, John!
false
Hi, !
false
```

Comment: This is like the tenth time a question with similar code is posted, is this from a textbook or something ?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: Works just like intended for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/KKptb/

Comment: Oh I missed the "empty string" part, my bad. Now I get what @adeneo meant with the dupe quesitons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to `window.name` in the second instance, which is an existing (defined) variable.  There is some documentation provided by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name).  It seems to be an empty string by default.

In adeneo's link, (http://jsfiddle.net/KKptb/) the output is:

```
"Hi, John!"
false
"Hi, result!"
false
```

because jsFiddle declares the iframe with `name="result"`

```
<iframe name="result" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/KKptb/show/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```